# CodeIgniter pagination and routes removing index

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Using CodeIgniter (CI) 3, I am able to retrieve records from my database and display pagination that works. Now I would like to tidy up the URLs.

I want the URL to look like this;

- page 1 `example.com/search?q=123`
- page 2 `example.com/search/10?q=123`
- page 3 `example.com/search/20?q=123`

Instead, they display like this;

- page 1 `example.com/search?q=123`
- page 2 `example.com/search/index/10?q=123`
- page 3 `example.com/search/index/20?q=123`

Notice that on pages 2 and 3 there is `index`. This is what I want to remove.

I have read through the [documentation regarding routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=route), but I can't get it to work.

A sample of my code is below for reference.

#### Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $search_term = $this->input->get('q');
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'search/index';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->search_model->item_list_count($search_term);
        $config['per_page'] = 10;

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    }

}
```

#### File *routes.php*

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
```

Whenever I remove `/index` from `base_url`, the URL in the address bar successfully changes, but page 1 simply refreshes. I don't see any new data and don't move on to page 2 of my results.

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'search';
```

I have also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712743/pagination-with-codeigniter-without-index-function). Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the index.php in the pagination URL, go to the *Config/App.php* file.

Change `public $indexPage = 'index.php';` to `public $indexPage = '';`

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Change the base URL in your pagination configuration to this:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'search';
```

Comment: Thanks @ShoeLace1291, when I do that the URL changes in the address bar but the page simply refreshes displaying the same results. The offset doesn't work :/ I have updated my question.